# How to substitute regex in AWK?

Tags: awk

What is the easiest way to substitute regular expression by AWK script? 
 
My goal is to search pattern:

```
/a|b/
```

in sentence:

```
I read a book "GAWK: Effective AWK Programming", but I can not figure it out.
```

and substitute it with:

```
ABC/a|b/ABC
```

So result will be:

```
I reABCaABCd ABCaABC ABCbABCook "GAWK: Effective AWK ProgrABCaABCmming", but I cABCaABCn not figure it out.
```

Comment: Is there any other reason for using `awk`? There is `sed` for this sort of things.

Comment: I formatted your question for you (see how I indented the text 4 spaces). [edit] your question to explain what `ABC/a|b/ABC` means to you and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with:

```
$ awk '{ gsub(/[ab]/,"ABC&ABC")}1' file 
I reABCaABCd ABCaABC ABCbABCook "GAWK: Effective AWK ProgrABCaABCmming", ABCbABCut I cABCaABCn not figure it out.
```

where file is:

```
I read a book "GAWK: Effective AWK Programming", but I can not figure it out.
```

Comment: you don't need pipe in the charset.  Also will not filter out any lines where the replacement doesn't happen (including empty lines)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` might be better for this task

```
echo "I re..." | sed 's/[ab]/ABC&ABC/g'
```